# Can't get text from a JTextField via Anonymous class

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Basically, this is what needs to happen:

1. Submit button is clicked, the actionlistener picks it up and prints what is in the textfield at the time of submission.

For some reason, it isn't picking up the text inside the textbox?
The "Submit Button Pressed" is getting printed by the way!
This is a silly problem but I am not used to anonymous classes. I believe the problem is the variable modifier. Here is my code simplified:

```
 public class MainWindw extends JFrame {

 public static  JTextField txt1;
 final JButton submit;

 public MainWindw()
 {
  //add panel...add textfield etc..
  txt1 = new JTextField();
  submit = new JButton("Submit");


       submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            System.out.println("Submit button pressed" + txt1.getText());}

        }
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: `submit.addActionListener` Where is this being called? Seems like you have it just floating around in the field, which would give a compile error. Also, is "*Submit button pressed*" getting printed?

Comment: In the constructor, sorry.

Comment: Please post a small compilable runnable program that we can test, and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Uncompilable snippets are usually worthless. You're asking "why isn't my code working?", well please let us find out.

Comment: The "Submit button pressed" is getting printed yes.

Comment: no its not my complete code, my code runs fine, the text in the printLine even gets printed. So it has to be the visibility modifier or something

Comment: We don't know. Use a debugger. Not enough information to help you. I'd say that `txt1` being static looks extra suspicious.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question in its current form other than to say that you've got a bug in code not shown. Sorry but I've got to give this a -1 down-vote as an incomplete question. Please improve it and post your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can remove this vote, and so someone has a chance of answering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this solution, and it works. i honestrly don't see any problem in your code except some Compilation Error but i think is cause you have simplified the code

```
public static JTextField txt1;
final JButton submit;

public MainWindw()
{
    JFrame panel = new JFrame();
    txt1 = new JTextField();
    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(txt1);
    panel.add(submit);
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Submit button pressed" + txt1.getText());
        }
    });
    panel.setSize(300, 300);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: greatly appreciated, this reminded me of something I left out. Thank you for not being like the others above me and down voting my post because I simplified my code.

Comment: @user2855405: all he did was show that your posted code doesn't show the error, something we've been **telling** you. What did you leave out?

Comment: You are welcome, can't vote down a question, question are made to learn ;)

Comment: Yes you can down vote, if the question is asked in such a way that helps no one in the future. We still have absolutely no idea what was wrong with his initial code, and you can up-vote questions if they're improved. I'm still hoping to do this.